# Looping through `readarray` inside a TikZ environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, readarray

In Tikz, how can I loop through a `readarray` object?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}

\usepackage{tikz,csvsimple}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
    1,2,3
    4,5,6
    7,8,9
    10,11,12
    13,14,15
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    \readdef{\jobname.csv}\namedata
    \readarray\namedata\names[-,\ncols]

    \ncols % Checking the number of columns

    \nrows % Checking the number of rows

    \names[2,2] and \names[3,3] % Checking some of the entries

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \rr in {1,2,...\nrows}
        {
            \draw (\names[\rr,1],\names[\rr,2]) circle (\names[\rr,3]); % fails at this line
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By including the missing comma before `\nrows` in  `\foreach \rr in {1,2,...\nrows}` ...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sounds like an answer.